# how query with try_catch executes with if else statements as show below

Tags: sql, if-statement, try-catch, execution

```
begin try 

    DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(200)  
    DECLARE @MaxUserCode INT

    BEGIN TRANSACTION ADM_UPD_SalesUserDetails   

            IF 1=0
            BEGIN      
                SET @Message = 'fail'
                RAISERROR(@Message,16,1)
            END 

    insert into test values(1,'pass')
    commit TRANSACTION ADM_UPD_SalesUserDetails  

end try

begin catch

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ADM_UPD_SalesUserDetails 

    if @Message='fail'
    select 'insert'
    else 
    select 'ok' 

end catch
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above query, the IF condition returns false (1=0) and it inserts the value to the TEST table. The script inside the catch Blocks will not be executed.

NOTE: CATCH statements will be execute only if an error has occurred in the statements within the TRY block.

Comment: Thanks for explanation